# Flatten symlink for Virtualbox Share

Tags: virtualbox, symbolic-link

I have a Virtualbox machine that I use for development, and I mount a directory for a project I'm working on within it. This directory has symlinks to a few other directories around my host file system for external libraries and the like.

When I mount the host filesystem in Virtualbox, the symlinks are preserved, but as their targets do not exist they are broken. Is there any way to have Virtualbox "flatten" the symlinks so that they appear properly to the guest?